# Qt installation with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, user-interface, coding-style

I'm trying to install qt 5.6.0 alpha in visual studio 2013

i'm getting the following error.Need help for the same:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'debug\torrent.exe'

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x450'                                      Stop.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'                                       Stop.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'                           Stop.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'                           Stop.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'                           Stop.

C:\QT\5.6.0\qtbase>

Comment: For mobile GUI you can use [QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html)([Qt Quick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-index.html) module) from [Qt](http://www.qt.io/developers/). For classic GUI use [QtWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I deduce that you are new to GUI programming. Since you have tagged Qt in the question, I believe you are considering Qt to develop your solution.

I suggest you go through Qt documentation and write some simple example programs. Even better would be to begin with [Voidrealms'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KtOzh0StTc&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63) excellent Qt tutorial videos.

That should get you on track.

Comment: yes, i want to go with Qt but the problem i'm facing with qt is, that how to integrate the Qt libraries with Visual Studio 2013. I you know can you suggest me something.

Comment: I already gave you the right suggestion in the answer.